# OrderBy list by a nested list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a objectA list, each one contain an another objectB list.
I'm trying to OrderBy each objectB list with an (int) Id :

```
var sorted = objectA.OrderBy(a => a.ObjectB.OrderBy(b => b.Id)).ToList();
```

Of course, this doesn't work. Someone have an advice ?

Comment: Please clarify with an example. Which element of the `ObjectB` list should be used for comparison?

Comment: can you give an example? maybe try to give a sample collection.

Comment: just orderby objectB:  `objectA.ToList().ForEch(a => a.ObjectB.OrderBy(b => b.Id));`

Comment: @Tim.Tang This gives nothing. Even, if you want to change the collection inside `ForEach`, it will not work. The collection used in foreach is immutable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to sort each `ObjectB` list in place (i.e. modify it), then simply use the [`List<T>.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3da4abas(v=vs.110).aspx) method. You will need to specify a custom [`Comparison<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh(v=vs.110).aspx) delegate:

```
foreach (var a in objectA)
{
   a.ObjectB.Sort((x, y) => x.Id - y.Id)
}
```

If `objectA` is a `List<ObjectA>`, then you can use the [`ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx) method and pass a delegate:

```
objectA.ForEach(a => a.ObjectB.Sort((x, y) => x.Id - y.Id));
```

If you don't want to modify your original `ObjectA` instances, then you will have to project each `ObjectA` instance into a new instance (by cloning it) and then assign sorted `ObjectB` lists. It would look something like (presuming that all properties have public setters):

```
var newList = objectA
    .Select(x => new ObjectA()
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        SomethingElse = x.SomethingElse,
        ObjectB = x.ObjectB.OrderBy(b => b.Id).ToList()
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: only if `ObjectB` is a `List<>`!

Comment: int doesn't have an Id property.

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare extension method and use it at a generic way. For first, helpers for `Expression`:

```
public static void SetProperty<T, B>(
                        this Expression<Func<T, B>> propertySelector, 
                        T target, 
                        B value)
{
  SetObjectProperty(target, propertySelector, value);
}

public static void SetObjectProperty<T, B>(
                             T target, 
                             Expression<Func<T, B>> propertySelector, 
                             object value)
{
  if (target == null)
  {
    throw new ArgumentNullException("target");
  }

  if (propertySelector == null)
  {
    throw new ArgumentNullException("propertySelector");
  }

  var memberExpression = propertySelector.Body as MemberExpression;
  if (memberExpression == null)
  {
    throw new NotSupportedException("Cannot recognize property.");
  }

  var propertyInfo = memberExpression.Member as PropertyInfo;
  if (propertyInfo == null)
  {
    throw new NotSupportedException(
                       "You can select property only."
                       + " Currently, selected member is: " 
                       + memberExpression.Member);
  }

  propertyInfo.SetValue(target, value);
}
```

Then write this extension:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> OrderInnerCollection<TSource, TInner, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Expression<Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TInner>>> innerSelector,
    Func<TInner, TKey> keySelector)
{
    var innerSelectorDelegate = innerSelector.Compile();
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        var collection = innerSelectorDelegate(item);
        collection = collection.OrderBy(keySelector);
        innerSelector.SetProperty(item, collection);

        yield return item;
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
var result = objectA.OrderInnerCollection(
                           aObj => aObj.ObjectB, 
                           objB => objB.Id).ToList();
```

Comment: Why would you use an expression to select the inner list, instead of a plain delegate?

Comment: Yeah, agree - but that are extension methods, what's more it is very generic ;)

Comment: @Groo - if it was delegate, I wouldn't be able to set ordered collection (OrderBy returns new instance of `IEnumerable`) back to the propery. Thanks to Expression I can get propert info.

Comment: @pwas: that's true, you could have passed two separate delegates instead, I guess this is one parameter less. And that's presuming that the property indeed has a public setter, instead of OP just wanting to sort it in place. But using reflection for a task like this really seems a bit too much. :)