# How to receive messages in descending order according to time received

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, model-view-controller

This controller prints list of messages

```
public ActionResult Index(string username)
{
    User user = db.Users.Include(u => u.Messages).Where(u => u.Username == username).FirstOrDefault();
    user.Messages ??= new List<Message>();
    return View(user);
}
```

User model contains List of Message. Message model contains TimeReceived. How to edit the Linq to send List of messages in descending order of TimeReceived?

Comment: With the magic of `OrderByDescending`

Comment: I've tried this already. How will you fetch TimeReceived from list of Messages? OrderBy(u => u.Messages.TimeReceived). Not working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OrderBy list by a nested list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259173/orderby-list-by-a-nested-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't actually given much information to work with.. the solutions you tried. I assume you are trying to order on the `IEnumerable<Message> user.Messages`. Try this..

```
user.Messages = user.Messages.OrderBy(x => x.TimeReceived).ToList();
```